# Request and/or receive money via transferwise ~ WISE with a Balance Account Invitation Link

Tags: payment, banking, payout, transferwise

I am new to transferwise and want to ask if the thing i want to do is achiviable via the wise-api

The platform/business needs to automate one action among others:

1. Business need to ask the User to pay via Wise whenever they feel like ready.
2. Business give the balance account details (Wise balance account) (i think it is the borderless account, right? or is one of the overseas balance accounts [usd, eur, gbp...] )
3. User pay to business
4. Via webhook (i think so) we manage the user info and linked the stuff to the DB

- Would be nice if i can use the "Request money" flow-endpoint which give you a payment-link with 14 days of exp. But i think you can't use that in the api :(

Are someone who made something like this before using wise?

I'm so new to wise and it is my first time implementing a thing like this from scratch (i'm the only backend dev haha)

I tried to folllow the docs, and i see the endpoints to do this in the Postman Collection, but i dont know if can solve the needs of the business.

[image]

If this the only way?
I cant use the "Request money" flow with the api?

Big thanks for reading!